# How do I specify a vmoptions file when running Java

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I am trying to streamline the execution of my Java application by creating a `.vmoptions` file which contains all of the arguments I would normally provide by command line (such as `-Dhttp.proxyHost=...`). I have seen this file format used by multiple applications (AndroidStudio, IntelliJ, Install4, Luciad) but cannot see how they are actually specifying which `.vmoptions` file to use. Sometimes it looks like the `.vmoptions` file is located next to the .class file (with the same name as the Main class...), sometimes it has a generic name like `default.vmoptions`. Till now, my best guess has been that it is automatically loaded based on file name and location within the class path.

My concrete question: How do I specify which `.vmoptions` file to use OR, where do I have to place a `.vmoptions` file in order for Java to automatically recognise it?

Comment: The named tools have custom launchers which take care of reading such option files and hence, decide where to look for them. The standard launcher, at least in the most recent JDK version, supports an environment variable, `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`, that may contain command line options and a special option, `@filename`, that directs it to read additional options from the specified file. These feature can be combined, i.e. set `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` to `@filename` or `option @filename another_option @other_filename`, to get what you want. But I don’t know in which version this support has been added.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it! In my case I will match the exisitng .vmoptions "format" for familiarity and load it as an external text file from my batch file / exe.

Comment: [Official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/java.html#using-the-jdk_java_options-launcher-environment-variable), for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation, [states](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-jvm-options), that the default options used to run IntelliJ IDEA are specified in the following files:

```
<IDE_HOME>\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions (for the default 64-bit JVM)
<IDE_HOME>\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions (for the optional 32-bit JVM)
```

You can override these files by adding the `IDEA_VM_OPTIONS` environment variable and specify the location of the file[s] with your preferred JVM options as its value. This file will override both the original default file and the copy located in the IntelliJ IDEA configuration directory.

Comment: How does this relate to my question? I am not asking how to configure IntelliJ, rather my own "native java" application?

Comment: *My concrete question: How do I specify which .vmoptions file to use OR, where do I have to place a .vmoptions file in order for Java to automatically recognise it?* - isn't this your very question?; or this *but cannot see how they are actually specifying which .vmoptions file to use.*.. no? am I mistaken?

Comment: If you want to use `.vmoptions` file outside of IDE, in your `shell` to run the Java class or jar file with it, then I would like to tell you, that `.vmoptions` is a domain-specific file for IDEs, and it doesn't belong to JLS.